# Can not decode base64 string properly with javascript atob function

Tags: javascript, base64, special-characters, decode

I'm working with other company to sending and receiving data in real time.

They give me a websocket URL like this: `ws://domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket` and I need to connect to it for transfer data.

The problem is they said that data is encoded with base64 string, and when I received data, I couldn't completely decode it. When I decode data by `atob()` function it show readable string but it had some special characters which I couldn't understand.

For example, here is one of the response messages in websocket:
`h6d1c2VyS2V50Rqdom5v0wAAAYSBGgjtp3ZlcnNpb26mMS4xMy4wqXNlc3Npb25JZLAxNjY4NjEzMDI0NDM0NDM0o3NpZ6Cmc3luY0lkAKRib2R5gad1c2VyS2V50Rqd`

When I decode base64 string, the result is:
`\x87§userKeyÑ\x1A\x9D¢noÓ\x00\x00\x01\x84\x81\x1A\bí§version¦1.13.0©sessionId°1668613024434434£sig ¦syncId\x00¤body\x81§userKeyÑ\x1A\x9D`

I simply decode it by `atob(encodedData)`, and get back result like this. I don't know what problem is. How should I fix this?

Comment: FYI : that base64 string you provided has errors, and it contains invalid characters. Even Node.js' `Buffer.from(s, 'base64')` (as suggested in the answer below) produces the same corrupt string than atob.

Answer (score 0):

Using the atob function is deprecated and I suggest you this little snippet to decode base64 encoded strings:

```
const encoded = "SOME_BASE64_STRING"
const decoded = new Buffer(encoded , "base64").toString()
```

Edit:
For client-side usage without the browserify module I recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/feross/buffer) package.

Comment: This is only true for Node.js. `atob` and `btoa` are not deprecated in the standard, and the `Buffer` class and isn't even available outside of node.js